# wordpress woocommerce message color changing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have changed the colour of the woocommerce "This product has been added to your cart message" for my site from gray to green.

On the desktop, when you add a product to the cart, the message comes up gray for a second and then changes to the green. How can I stop this message bar 'jumping'?

I used the following css code but I can't figure out why it still turns gray for a second first. It only does this on the desktop.

```
.woocommerce-message.lsx-woocommerce-message-wrap{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #c1e3b2;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: It's hard to say for certain without more code but it's likely that you overrode the default with your own css correct? If that's the case it may be loading the other first before applying your css.

Comment: Thanks. I think I did override it but I've fixed it by changing the default.

Comment: The text size is still jumping. There's a piece of code in the bootstrap.css file that says the following. How do I change it so it will just override the size for this item, not all the body text in the site???                                                      body {
    font-family: "Noto Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

Comment: You can try adding font-size to the css you posted above to your requisite size. Without knowing the element's class or your layout I can't say for sure which element you need to target.

Comment: Cool, it worked. Thanks so much!!